# FindControl() not getting value from input textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html

I am working on a website that has input boxes which are capable of being edited. The boxes are populated from an SQL call on PageLoad() and each text box is assigned with the ID "txtz" and then the ID number from the SQL row.

I want the user to be able to edit the text box, and upon clicking a html button have the values from the input boxes stored in a variable that can be used to Update the SQL data.

My issue is that when I call CType(FindControl it is having difficulties locating the instance of the object... I would be very grateful for any and all help!

*Note* When I alert the variable created for the input ID it matches what is displayed as the inputs ID on the browser... leaving me to think the FindControl function is the issue.

I have attached two images from my code in hopes that it may assist!

[Table Creation in PageLoad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0Hbt.png)

[Procedure on Button Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRUtS.png)

---

```
    Sub UpdatePostDB(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim ButtonID As String = sender.ID
        Dim ButtonID2 As String() = ButtonID.Split("z")
        Dim placeholder As String = ButtonID(0)
        Dim realID As String = ButtonID(2) & ButtonID(3) & ButtonID(4)

        Dim titleinput As String = "txtz" & realID
        Dim messgeinput As String = "txtz" & realID

        Dim Titl As String = CType(FindControl(titleinput), HtmlInputText).Value
        Dim Messge As String = Request.QueryString("txt2z" & realID)

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "titlealert", "alert('Title: " & titleinput & "');", True)

    End Sub
```

---

```
                cm1.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ManagerPosts WHERE Department = '" & DeptDDL2.SelectedItem.Text & "' And DateAdded >= DATEADD(DAY,-14,GETDATE()) ORDER BY DateAdded ASC"
                dr1 = cm1.ExecuteReader
                If dr1.HasRows Then
                    While dr1.Read

                        Dim viewannouncement As New TableCell() With {.HorizontalAlign=HorizontalAlign.Center}
                        Dim viewannounce As New CheckBox With {.ID = dr1.Item("ID"), .AutoPostBack = True}
                        AddHandler viewannounce.CheckedChanged, AddressOf viewannounce_CheckedChanged

                    Dim updateCell As New TableCell()
                    Dim updatebutt As New Button With {.ID = "bz" & dr1.Item("ID"), .Text = "Update Post", .Height = 25%, .Width = 85%}
                    AddHandler updatebutt.Click, AddressOf UpdatePostDB

                        Dim tr As New TableRow
                        If dr1("Visible") = "N" Then
                        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = "<div style='background-color:white'><input runat='server' id=txtz" & dr1.Item("ID") & " type='text' style='width:100%;' value='" & dr1("Title") & "'/><br /><input id=txt2z" & dr1.Item("ID") & " type='text' style='width:100%;' value='" & dr1("Message") & "'/></div"})


                        viewannouncement.Controls.Add(viewannounce)
                        tr.Cells.Add(viewannouncement)
                        ManageTable.Rows.Add(tr)

                        updateCell.CssClass = "buttonup"
                        updateCell.Controls.Add(updatebutt)
                        tr.Cells.Add(updateCell)
                        ManageTable.Rows.Add(tr)

                        Else
                        tr.Cells.Add(New TableCell With {.Text = "<div style='background-color:white'><input id=txtz" & dr1.Item("ID") & " type='text' style='background-color: #ff66ff; width:100%;' value='" & dr1("Title") & "'/><br /><input id=txt2z" & dr1.Item("ID") & " type='text' style='background-color: #ff66ff; width:100%;' value='" & dr1("Message") & "'/></div"})

                            If dr1.Item("ID") = viewannounce.ID Then
                                viewannounce.Checked = True
                            End If
                            viewannouncement.Controls.Add(viewannounce)
                            tr.Cells.Add(viewannouncement)
                        ManageTable.Rows.Add(tr)

                        updateCell.CssClass = "buttonup"
                        updateCell.Controls.Add(updatebutt)
                        tr.Cells.Add(updateCell)
                        ManageTable.Rows.Add(tr)

                        End If
                    End While
                End If
```

---

**Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

Line 146:            Dim messgeinput As String = "txtz" & realID

Line 147:

Line 148:            Dim Titl As String = CType(FindControl(titleinput), HtmlInputText).Value

Line 149:            Dim Messge As String = Request.QueryString("txt2z" & realID)

Line 150:**

Comment: Some of us don't have access to imgur at work. Please consider including your code directly in the question.

Comment: thank you @ArcaneCraeda I have added the code to my post, hope that helps!